# How to persist Spark Dataset to MAPR HDFS and GCP storage

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to find out if it's possible to make a simple spark program, which runs on MAPR cluster, which persists the result dataset into local HDFS and GCP storage.

I understand that it can be done with **gsutil** to copy files from HDFS to GCS, but it's not what I'm looking for.

please see a simplified code in spark-shell

```
val ds = spark.read.textFile("/some/location/input.txt")
ds.write.save("/some/location/result.txt")
ds.write.save("gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/result.txt")
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Google's cloud storage connector is exactly what solves this for their manager hadoop and spark offering dataproc. Read about it here. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage

Comment: I'll try it, thanks